# Can't create java project in IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

I'm very new to IntelliJ IDEA plz bear with me.
I have set the SDK's JDK1.8 and Android SDK in the setting and I can create and run Android programs with out any problem.
But for creating a Java project, when I select "File > New Project > Java" it shows only a single option Groovy. I don't understand what went wrong. Plz help.

[image]

Comment: maven projects can also be java applications. Maven just builds them.

Comment: Is it not possible to create simple Java application without maven/gradle/grovey in this IDE..?

Comment: Yes it is, have a read here: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Setting_up_a_project_in_IntelliJ_IDEA if something is missing you may have not installed the neccessary IntelliJ Plugins at installation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm using IntelliJ 13 and the tutorial is not compatible with my version, i checked few tutorials but in all that when they click on Java in New Project, different type of Java project options come up but not in my case. Also I had installed and set JDK correctly.

Comment: Deselect everything and press next.

Comment: It worked..Thank you @SatelliteSD...and sorry for asking such a silly question.

Comment: just set the path variable for jdk and sdk both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said you want a simple java project just follow like this

*File -> new project -> java (without selecting any thing) -> next ->(without selecting any thing) next ->Give your project name -> finish*

Answer (score 0):

Community Edition dont work with: Spring, Java EE, Micronaut, Quarkus, Helidon, and more
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows